# FakeRaid using Intel RST, Ubuntu Server reported correct size, but Ubuntu desktop reported small size

Tags: server, 20.04, intel, rst, fakeraid

A Raid 10 was setup through Intel RST with 4 3TB hard drives.

Ubuntu Server 20.04 reported correct size via lsblk, see picture 1.  However, Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 reported much smaller size, see picture 2.

Do anyone know and how to fixed it in Desktop?

[Ubuntu Server reported correct FakeRaid 10 size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66HvH.jpg)
[Ubuntu Desktop reported smaller FakeRaid 10 size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca6I8.jpg)

Comment: Please don't upload pictures of your terminal. Provide the command and copy/paste the corresponding output in the body of your question and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Further investigation, when set the computer (Dell Precision T7600) boot to UEFI, booting with gparted-live-1.3.0-1-amd64, gparted detected the Raid10 drive.  But when I tried to partition and format the Raid10 drive with ext4, I got 1.7TB out of the 5.1TB.  However, with ntfs, I got the full 5.1TB.

Comment: Switch to Legacy boot, using the same gparted live CD, I was able to partition and format with ext4 and had the full capacity, 5.1TB.

Comment: To clarify my original post, the command used to get the results was "lsblk".  To avoid any potential contamination, ubuntu server 20.04 was freshly installed.  The were no screen capturing software and SSH; just the raw image from the monitor; thus the picture.  The same was for Ubuntu desktop, no modification, no additional softwares.  Picture was obtained with 'lsblk'.  Same picture was obtain disregarded UEFI or Legacy boot BIOS setting.